# "So wenig Frauen" oder "so wenige Frauen"?

Tags: style, inflection

Bei der Formulierung einer erläuternden Mitteilung für eine Ausstellung stoße ich auf folgendes Problem: Heißt es richtig

> (1) Warum sind hier so **wenig** Frauen abgebildet?

oder

> (2) Warum sind hier so **wenige** Frauen abgebildet?

(1) kommt mir richtiger vor, aber ich fürchte, dass Frauen sich sprachlich missachtet fühlen, weil *wenig* so dinghaft klingt. (2) kommt mir sprachsensibilitätsmäßig sicherer vor, aber gleichzeitg sträubt sich mein Stilistik-Nackenfell.

Was ist richtig? Was soll ich tun?

Ergänzend vielleicht

> (3) Warum sind hier **nur wenige** Frauen abgebildet

kommt wir wieder richtig vor (besser als "nur wenig Frauen"). Rätselhaft, rätselhaft...

Comment: Ich würde dringend zu *wenige* raten, weil die Frauen sicher zählbar sind und sich nur unter Protest in die Kategorie *wenig Salz* oder *viel Mehl* pressen lassen- kann man am Nackenfell etwas machen?

Comment: Warum wurde diese interessante Frage abgewertet?

Comment: Könnte man sich denken, dass die unflektierte Variante ein Adverb wäre, das sich nicht auf "Frauen" sondern auf "abgebildet" bezieht?

Comment: @Beta: Meinst Du etwas wie "Frauen sind hier so wenig abgebildet wie auf der Rückseite"? Im präsentierten Satz (1) eigentlich nicht.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die aufmerksamen Kommentare so weit. Mit Eurer Hilfe (und vielleicht infolge -zigfachen Durchlesens der Sätze) habe ich mich inzwischen an "Warum sind hier nur so wenige Frauen abgebildet" gewöhnt. Sehr einleuchtend finde ich das Argument, dass "wenig" für Nichtzählbares einzusetzen ist (wie Mehl und Milch), "wenige" für Zählbares (wie Eier und Frauen). Huch...

Answer (score 7):

Duden Band 9 – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* meint, dass das Indefinitum *wenig* vor Substantiven ohne attributives Adjektiv im Singular meist, im Plural recht häufig unflektiert bleibt (im Genitiv Plural steht dagegen immer die Form mit Flexionsendung):

> Dazu gehört wenig Mut.
>   Ich habe wenig Hoffnung.
>   Es gibt wenig Augenblicke, in denen ich die Nerven verliere.
>   Er begann mit wenig Aussichten auf Erfolg.
>   (Aber Genitiv Plural: Es war das Werk weniger Augenblicke.)

Comment: Könnte man hier noch eine Erklärung für Nichtlinguisten hinzufügen? :)

Answer (score -2):

Fangen wir mit der leichtesten Übung an: der Singular "wenig" (genauso wie "viel" und ähliche Indefinita) wird verwendet, wenn das dadurch Beschriebene etwas *nicht* Zählbares darstellt. Hingegen wird der Plural "wenig*e*" verwendet, wenn es sich um unterscheidbare, zählbare Einzeldinge handelt:

> wenig Salz, viel Mehl

dagegen:

> wenig*e* Löffel Salz, viel*e* Säcke Mehl

Das Mehl und das Salz sind zwar Dinge, die sich nur durch eine Mengenangabe quantifizieren lassen, aber *Löffel* oder ein *Säcke*, voll mit irgendwas, sind durchaus zählbar.

Stellt sich also die Frage, warum

> Warum sind hier so wenig Frauen abgebildet?

das Sprachgefühl nicht stört? Weil sich das "wenig", sofern es im Singular steht, nicht als nähere Bestimmung des Substantivs "Frau", sondern des Verbs "abbilden" herausstellt. Die Frage lautet eigentlich:

> Warum ist (wird) hier so wenig abgebildet?

Und die "Frauen" sind lediglich eine Präzisierung dessen, was eigentlich *wenig abgebildet* wird.

Natürlich geht auch die Konstruktion auch mit dem Plural:

> Warum sind hier so wenige Frauen abgebildet?

aber dann hätte der Satz einen anderen Sinn. Dann lautete die Frage nämlich nicht, warum so wenig abgebildet wird (und zwar Frauen), sondern, warum (zwar ausreichend abgebildet wird, aber) sich so wenige Frauen unter den Abbildungen finden. Die Frauen sind zählbar, der Akt der Abbildung als Kategorie nicht.

Und noch eine Zusatzbemerkung: nicht nur Nicht-Zählbares wird mit dem Singular konstruiert, sondern auch jede Art von Kategorie:

> Dieser Teig ist mit wenigen Eiern gemacht.
> In der Mayonaise ist wenig Ei enthalten.

Im ersten Fall ist von einer zählbaren Anzahl von Eiern die Rede und diese Anzahl ist gering - weils nur "wenige" sind. Im zweiten Fall handelt es sich um ein Verhältnis und da werden nicht die einzelnen Eier gezählt, sondern die Menge, die sie, im Verhältnis zur Gesamtmenge, darstellen. Wenn man einen riesigen Haufen Mayonnaise macht, dann kann man durchaus "viele" Eier dafür verwenden und trotzdem ist in der entstehenden Masse "wenig Ei" enthalten.

Comment: Nein. Die Frage lautet nicht: *»Warum ist (wird) hier so wenig abgebildet?«* Man stelle sich ein Bild vor, auf dem alle europäischen Regierungschefs und -chefinnen abgebildet sind. Oder ein Collage mit den Portraits aller Physik-Nobelpreisträger. Oder ein Bild aller Personen, die jemals das Wiener Neujahrskonzert dirigiert haben. Die Liste des Beispiele ist endlos. Auf all diesen Bildern wird man viele Männer sehen, und niemand wird fragen *»Warum ist (wird) hier so wenig abgebildet?«* Die Frage ist *»Warum sind hier so wenige Frauen abgebildet?«*

Comment: Wollen wir jetzt eine Diskussion über Deine SteckenpferdInnen führen, oder über Grammatik? Die Antwort auf die Frage, wie der Physik-Nobelpreis verliehen wird, kannst Du schwerlich von mir verlangen und schon gar nicht hier, denn das wäre off-topic. Daß ich die Frage so umformuliert habe, war dafür gedacht, die *Konstruktion* zu erläutern. Selbstverständlich wird hier gefragt warum so wenig - was? - abgebildet wird, genauso, wie in Mayonaise "wenig Ei" enthalten sein kann - bzw., korrekterweise - wenig EiInnen.

Comment: Ich halte diese Antwort für falsch, denn sie geht davon aus, dass nur *unzählbare* Mengen das unflektierte "wenig" tragen dürfen - was nicht stimmt: https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/unternehmen/zu-wenig-autos-18943718.html und Duden Band 9 - wie in der (richtigeren) Antwort zitiert - hat auch eine abweichende Meinung.